# Adding ForeignKeys to a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl

I'm using PostgreSQL for a school project and I'm trying to add different foreign keys to my database tables but when i run for example:

```
ALTER TABLE PARTSUPP ADD FOREIGN KEY (PS_SUPPKEY) REFERENCES SUPPLIER(S_SUPPKEY);
```

on the SQL shell I receive the following error message:

```
server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Failed.
```

I hope that you can help me with this problem!

Comment: What is your exact Postgres version? `select version();` will tell you

Comment: PostgreSQL 12.1

Answer (score 0):

Your PostgreSQL server is crashing when you run your statement. There may be more information available in the Postgres logs.

Comment: Where i can find that log file that you mentioned? I've searched but i can't find it

Comment: it will be on the server where Postgres is running.  I'd give more information, but the exact answer depends on how/where Postgres was installed.

Comment: @RicardoPaiva: https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2014/11/12/dear-postgresql-where-are-my-logs